# Why my Iterator in singly linked list always returns same first value

Tags: java, oop, iterator, singly-linked-list

So i have to implement logic to some kind of game where we add units to armies and they can fight. Right now i created new game character named Dragon. Dragon has to do mass damage to every single unit in opposite army every 3 rounds. I can't resolve why my iterator always returns same element so instead of hitting every single unit i hit X times only the first one. There is my code

Hit method in Dragon class implementation:

```
  @Override
    public void hit(CanReceiveDamage opponent) {
        rounds++;
        if(opponent instanceof ArmyWarrior armyUnit && rounds==3){
                if(armyUnit.hasNext()) {
                    armyUnit.next().receiveDamage(() -> FIRE_BREATH_MASS_DAMAGE);
                }
        }
    }
```

Interface ArmyWarrior:

```
public interface ArmyWarrior {
    Warrior getWarriorBehind();
    Warrior next();
    boolean hasNext();

}
```

`getWarriorBehind()` method works perfectly fine with this implementation:

```
@Override
        public Warrior getWarriorBehind() {

            return next == head ? null : next.warrior;
        }
```

Army class and nested Node class:

```
public class Army implements Iterable<Warrior> {

 private class Node extends Warrior implements ArmyWarrior, IHealer {
        Warrior warrior;
        Node next;

        public Node(Warrior warrior) {
            this.warrior = warrior;
            this.next = this;
        }

 @Override
        public Warrior next() {
            if(!hasNext()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return iterator().next();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(next!=head){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

And my iterator:

```
public Iterator<Warrior> iterator() {
        return new SimpleIterator();
    }

private class SimpleIterator implements Iterator<Warrior> {

        Node cursor = head;


        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor.next != head;
        }

        @Override
        public Warrior next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            return cursor.next;
        }


    }
```

No matter how hard i try and how many different approaches i tried, nothing seems to work as it should, need some help

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, or is there a reason you're not using one of the pre-built list types?

Answer (score 2):

Here you create a new iterator each time the method is invoked:

```
    public Warrior next() {
        ...
        return iterator().next();
    }
```

You should either store this iterator somewhere and keep iterating using it. Or implement Linked List differently, e.g. by storing next Warrior right in the current one.

Comment: I tried to extract is somewhere else but i think im doing it wrong. Is there any chance you could show me where could i extract it to work as intended?

Comment: @Fellou98 Note that an iterator (which is basically a bookmark) has separate state (position) independent of the list (the book), and you could have several iterators active on one list at the same time. If your iterator doesn't have some `index` or similar variable, it can't do its job.